# Error: Problem validating fields in app.json

Tags: json, expo

This is a new error the app worked previously and no changes were made. Won't compile using Expo.

Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/ • should NOT have additional property 'displayName'.

(Entire app.json file)

{
"name": "InstagramPrepTS",
"displayName": "InstagramPrepTS"
}

Answer (score 1):

I went through a similar error. But was able to fix it, by just going into the app.json and changing the name from student-learner to studentLearner i.e i remove the "-" from the name. Because the slug name should not be the same as the name of the app i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to `expo-cli` may change what is/is-not a valid `app.json` configuration.

You'll need to remove the field it's complaining about, or possibly downgrade `expo-cli`, although I wouldn't recommend that.